# Deserializing XML to object winds up with everything null

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I am writing a C# library for consuming a service called PubMed. It's a public service run by the NIH, for the curious.

The service URL I'm using is [here](http://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esearch.fcgi?db=pubmed&term=cancer).

So I pulled the DTD down, used that to generate the XSD using VS2010. Then I used xsd.exe to generate a C# class (below).

```
using System;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace PubMedSearch
{
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.42000
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// 
// This source code was auto-generated by xsd, Version=4.0.30319.1.
// 


/// <remarks />
[GeneratedCode("xsd", "4.0.30319.1")]
[Serializable]
[DebuggerStepThrough]
[DesignerCategory("code")]
[XmlType(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/esearch")]
[XmlRoot(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/esearch", IsNullable = false)]
public class eSearchResult
{
    private ErrorList errorListField;

    private ItemsChoiceType[] itemsElementNameField;

    private object[] itemsField;

    private WarningList warningListField;

    /// <remarks />
    [XmlElement("Count", typeof (string))]
    [XmlElement("ERROR", typeof (string))]
    [XmlElement("IdList", typeof (IdList))]
    [XmlElement("QueryKey", typeof (string))]
    [XmlElement("QueryTranslation", typeof (string))]
    [XmlElement("RetMax", typeof (string))]
    [XmlElement("RetStart", typeof (string))]
    [XmlElement("TranslationSet", typeof (TranslationSet))]
    [XmlElement("TranslationStack", typeof (TranslationStack))]
    [XmlElement("WebEnv", typeof (string))]
    [XmlChoiceIdentifier("ItemsElementName")]
    public object[] Items
    {
        get { return itemsField; }
        set { itemsField = value; }
    }

    /// <remarks />
    [XmlElement("ItemsElementName")]
    [XmlIgnore]
    public ItemsChoiceType[] ItemsElementName
    {
        get { return itemsElementNameField; }
        set { itemsElementNameField = value; }
    }

    /// <remarks />
    public ErrorList ErrorList
    {
        get { return errorListField; }
        set { errorListField = value; }
    }

    /// <remarks />
    public WarningList WarningList
    {
        get { return warningListField; }
        set { warningListField = value; }
    }
}

/// <remarks />
[GeneratedCode("xsd", "4.0.30319.1")]
[Serializable]
[DebuggerStepThrough]
[DesignerCategory("code")]
[XmlType(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/esearch")]
[XmlRoot(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/esearch", IsNullable = false)]
public class IdList
{
    private string[] idField;

    /// <remarks />
    [XmlElement("Id")]
    public string[] Id
    {
        get { return idField; }
        set { idField = value; }
    }
}

/// <remarks />
[GeneratedCode("xsd", "4.0.30319.1")]
[Serializable]
[DebuggerStepThrough]
[DesignerCategory("code")]
[XmlType(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/esearch")]
[XmlRoot(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/esearch", IsNullable = false)]
public class TranslationSet
{
    private Translation[] translationField;

    /// <remarks />
    [XmlElement("Translation")]
    public Translation[] Translation
    {
        get { return translationField; }
        set { translationField = value; }
    }
}

/// <remarks />
[GeneratedCode("xsd", "4.0.30319.1")]
[Serializable]
[DebuggerStepThrough]
[DesignerCategory("code")]
[XmlType(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/esearch")]
[XmlRoot(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/esearch", IsNullable = false)]
public class Translation
{
    private string fromField;

    private string toField;

    /// <remarks />
    public string From
    {
        get { return fromField; }
        set { fromField = value; }
    }

    /// <remarks />
    public string To
    {
        get { return toField; }
        set { toField = value; }
    }
}

/// <remarks />
[GeneratedCode("xsd", "4.0.30319.1")]
[Serializable]
[DebuggerStepThrough]
[DesignerCategory("code")]
[XmlType(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/esearch")]
[XmlRoot(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/esearch", IsNullable = false)]
public class TranslationStack
{
    private object[] itemsField;

    /// <remarks />
    [XmlElement("OP", typeof (string))]
    [XmlElement("TermSet", typeof (TermSet))]
    public object[] Items
    {
        get { return itemsField; }
        set { itemsField = value; }
    }
}

/// <remarks />
[GeneratedCode("xsd", "4.0.30319.1")]
[Serializable]
[DebuggerStepThrough]
[DesignerCategory("code")]
[XmlType(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/esearch")]
[XmlRoot(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/esearch", IsNullable = false)]
public class TermSet
{
    private string countField;

    private string explodeField;

    private string fieldField;

    private string termField;

    /// <remarks />
    public string Term
    {
        get { return termField; }
        set { termField = value; }
    }

    /// <remarks />
    public string Field
    {
        get { return fieldField; }
        set { fieldField = value; }
    }

    /// <remarks />
    public string Count
    {
        get { return countField; }
        set { countField = value; }
    }

    /// <remarks />
    public string Explode
    {
        get { return explodeField; }
        set { explodeField = value; }
    }
}

/// <remarks />
[GeneratedCode("xsd", "4.0.30319.1")]
[Serializable]
[XmlType(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/esearch", IncludeInSchema = false)]
public enum ItemsChoiceType
{
    /// <remarks />
    Count,

    /// <remarks />
    ERROR,

    /// <remarks />
    IdList,

    /// <remarks />
    QueryKey,

    /// <remarks />
    QueryTranslation,

    /// <remarks />
    RetMax,

    /// <remarks />
    RetStart,

    /// <remarks />
    TranslationSet,

    /// <remarks />
    TranslationStack,

    /// <remarks />
    WebEnv
}

/// <remarks />
[GeneratedCode("xsd", "4.0.30319.1")]
[Serializable]
[DebuggerStepThrough]
[DesignerCategory("code")]
[XmlType(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/esearch")]
[XmlRoot(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/esearch", IsNullable = false)]
public class ErrorList
{
    private string[] fieldNotFoundField;

    private string[] phraseNotFoundField;

    /// <remarks />
    [XmlElement("PhraseNotFound")]
    public string[] PhraseNotFound
    {
        get { return phraseNotFoundField; }
        set { phraseNotFoundField = value; }
    }

    /// <remarks />
    [XmlElement("FieldNotFound")]
    public string[] FieldNotFound
    {
        get { return fieldNotFoundField; }
        set { fieldNotFoundField = value; }
    }
}

/// <remarks />
[GeneratedCode("xsd", "4.0.30319.1")]
[Serializable]
[DebuggerStepThrough]
[DesignerCategory("code")]
[XmlType(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/esearch")]
[XmlRoot(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/esearch", IsNullable = false)]
public class WarningList
{
    private string[] outputMessageField;

    private string[] phraseIgnoredField;

    private string[] quotedPhraseNotFoundField;

    /// <remarks />
    [XmlElement("PhraseIgnored")]
    public string[] PhraseIgnored
    {
        get { return phraseIgnoredField; }
        set { phraseIgnoredField = value; }
    }

    /// <remarks />
    [XmlElement("QuotedPhraseNotFound")]
    public string[] QuotedPhraseNotFound
    {
        get { return quotedPhraseNotFoundField; }
        set { quotedPhraseNotFoundField = value; }
    }

    /// <remarks />
    [XmlElement("OutputMessage")]
    public string[] OutputMessage
    {
        get { return outputMessageField; }
        set { outputMessageField = value; }
    }
}
}
```

It doesn't look like it matches too well with the XML, but I'm new at this so I give it a go. I use this code to make the request:

```
var request = WebRequest.Create(url);
        var response = request.GetResponse();

        var stream = response.GetResponseStream();

        var deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(eSearchResult), new XmlRootAttribute("eSearchResult"));
        var result = (eSearchResult)deserializer.Deserialize(stream);
```

And result ends up with null properties and fields. I'm really kind of working in the dark here. I followed what information I've been able to find to the letter and keep getting the same result. Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: Your generated code is expecting a namespace of `"http://tempuri.org/esearch"` but the sent XML has no namespace provided.  You either have to add a namespace to the XML or remove it from the generated class.  Neither one sounds like a good idea.

Comment: Well, that did fix the issue. If you want to submit it as an answer I'll mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The incoming XML did not have a namespace that is listed in the generated code.  Adding a namespace to the received XML will allow it to be deserialized.

```
        var request = WebRequest.Create(url);
        var response = request.GetResponse();

        var stream = response.GetResponseStream();

        var result = new eSearchResult();

        try
        {
            MemoryStream XmlStream = new MemoryStream();
            XmlDocument MyDoc = new XmlDocument();
            MyDoc.Load(stream);

            XmlAttribute AddNamespace = MyDoc.CreateAttribute("xmlns");
            AddNamespace.Value = "http://tempuri.org/esearch";
            MyDoc.LastChild.Attributes.Append(AddNamespace);
            MyDoc.Save(XmlStream);

            XmlStream.Position = 0;

            result = (eSearchResult)deserializer.Deserialize(XmlStream);
        }
        catch (Exception Error)
        { }
```